# How to write HTML code inside of DIV after send POST request in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to write HTML code inside of DIV after getting data from service but it doesn't work. These are my `html` and `js` codes. How can I fix?

Thanks.

**index.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
        <script src=script></script>
        </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <div ng-bind-html="htmlcode">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
        .controller('myController', ['$window', '$scope', '$http', function($window, $scope, $http) {

            html = "<ul><li>Item-1<ul><li>SubItem-1</li></ul></li><li>Item-2</li></ul>";
            $scope.htmlcode= html;

            var res = $http.post(service_url);

            res.success(function(result, status, headers, config) {

            });
        }]);
})(window.angular);
```

**script1.js:**

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
        .controller('myController', ['$window', '$scope', '$http', function($window, $scope, $http) {

            var res = $http.post(service_url);

            res.success(function(result, status, headers, config) {
                html = "<ul><li>Item-1<ul><li>SubItem-1</li></ul></li><li>Item-2</li></ul>";
                $scope.htmlcode= html;
            });
        }]);
})(window.angular);
```

**RESULT (script1.js):**

- Item 1
- Item 2

`SubItem-1` is not shown as a sub item of Item-1

**RESULT (script.js):**

- Item 1

  - SubItem-1
- Item 2

Comment: Can you append the html string to div..Is it worked

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj you mean appendChild or direcly append string to inside of div? my html string will contain some data from service.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. Don't you get some error in console? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/zp82e3xm/5/) I setup works fine. What is the difference between my code and your code?

Comment: @yazaki you don't do _post_ request :-)

Comment: @Elmi, if no errors in console try use [scope.$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) or [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout) in success callback

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood RESULT. @Elmi said **script1.js** works unexpectedly. Thxs @Grundy!

Comment: I setup a same code like yours in which I called $http.post function and set scope value in success function. The result was fine. Did you set  *server_url* variable correctly? Anyway your code structure is correct. Please check whether you get some error in console.

Comment: @yazaki can you show your code?

Comment: Sure. [This is the code.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/zp82e3xm/8/) But you know this code needs server which handles post request.

Comment: @yazaki yes server_url is correctly set. I look at your code it is same but I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

Comment: @Elmi, so, do you see any errors in console?

Comment: @Grundy no there is no any error in console.

Comment: @Elmi, in your `script1.js` first you assign html to global var `html` try assign it to `$scope.htmlcode` directly as in @yazaki sample

Comment: @Grundy it didn't work.

Comment: @Elmi, can you provide plunkr with your code? seems like you have some  other problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82066/discussion-between-grundy-and-elmi).

Answer (score 0):

Do not manipulate html inside the controller use diectives or services for that. This should be done with an ng-repeat instead.

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
        .controller('myController', ['$window', '$scope', '$http', function($window, $scope, $http) {

            $scope.items = [];

            var res = $http.post(service_url);

            res.success(function(result, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.items.concat(result.items);
            });
        }]);
})(window.angular);
```

// template

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <ul class="items">
               <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                 {{item.name}}
                 <ul class="sub-items">
                   <li ng-repeat="subitem in item.subItems">{{subitem.name}}</li>
                 </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
```

// items.json

```
{
  "items": [

    {
      "name": "item1",
      "subItems": [
        "name": "subItem1"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: No, This is a very strait forward problem. I don't see the need for injecting the html as a string. This is not very save and should be avoid. Instead describe the html structure on the template. This is the template responsability